# Dependent name lookup in function template: clang rejects, gcc accepts

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the following fragment:

```
struct X { };

namespace foo {
    template <class T>
    void bar() { T{} < T{}; }

    void operator<(const X&, const X&) {}
}

int main() {
    foo::bar<X>();
}
```

clang rejects this code, gcc accepts it. Is this a gcc bug or is this a clang bug?

Comment: I don't see how it is a bug because the type `T` can refer to any type. If that type `T` doesn't overload or support the `<` operator then the `bar` function would fail. Since you've overloaded the `<` operator it's all good. I guess it all goes down to how compilers read code, but semantics-wise it's not bug-prone.

Comment: @Poriferous That doesn't make any sense. The question is all about what the correct behavior of `bar()` is for types `T` that don't have `operator<`. The correct behavior is either: "yes, it finds `bar::operator<`" (in which case, clang has a bug) or "the code is ill-formed" (in which case, gcc has a bug).

Comment: That makes no sense because `bar` is a function and has no member `operator<`. Since you've defined `operator <` for struct `X`, I really don't see what the problem is here. Even if the operator overload were embedded in the struct `X` the code should still compile correctly. To be fair, it's clang that has the bug since it appears to assume what a type is. I mean, have you tried replacing `foo::bar<X>()` with something like `foo::bar<int>()` and see if clang rejects that code too?

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is a gcc bug, filed as [70099](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70099). From [temp.dep.res]:

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>   (1.1) — Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
>   (1.2) — Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context (14.6.4.1) and from the definition context.

`foo::operator<()` isn't visible at the point of definition of the template, and isn't in an associated namespace from the function arguments (`X`'s associated namespace is just the global namespace `::`). So I think gcc is wrong to find `foo::operator<` and clang is correct to reject the code.

Answer (score 8):

GCC is wrong Clang is correct. The fact that GCC swallows invalid code as the one that you showed is also mentioned in CLANG's compatibility page [here](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#dep_lookup).

Unqualified names are looked up in the following ways.

1. The compiler conducts unqualified lookup in the scope where the name was written. **For a template, this means the lookup is done at the point where the template is defined, not where it's instantiated.** Since `operator<` hasn't been declared yet at this point, unqualified lookup won't find it.
2. If the name is called like a function, then the compiler also does argument-dependent lookup (ADL). (Sometimes unqualified lookup can suppress ADL; see [basic.lookup.argdep] paragraph 3 for more information.) In ADL, the compiler looks at the types of all the arguments to the call. When it finds a class type, it looks up the name in that class's namespace; the result is all the declarations it finds in those namespaces, plus the declarations from unqualified lookup. However, the compiler doesn't do ADL until it knows all the argument types.