# error: no viable overloading with clang, compiles with gcc

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, language-lawyer

The following program compiles fine with g++ (version 10.1.0) but not with clang++ (10.0.0)

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename U>
struct A { U x; };

namespace tools {
  template <typename U>
  void operator+=(A<U>& lhs, const A<U>& rhs) { lhs.x += rhs.x; }
}

namespace impl {
  template <typename U = int>
  void f() {
    A<U> a{3};
    A<U> b{2};
    a += b;
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
  }
}

namespace impl {
  using namespace tools;
}

int main()
{
  impl::f();
}
```

The error is:

```
name.cpp:16:7: error: no viable overloaded '+='
    a += b;
    ~ ^  ~
name.cpp:27:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'impl::f<int>' requested here
  impl::f();
```

Clearly, moving the `using namespace tools` part before the template function `impl::f()` removes the error of clang.

**Additional note**
An important point here is that `f` is a template function. Without template parameters the code compiles neither with gcc, nor with clang.

What compiler is correct here? gcc or clang?

Comment: @francesco : Works for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The code is ill-formed** because the part of unqualified name look-up that is not argument dependent is performed in the template definition context. So Clang is right and the GCC bug is already reported ([bug #70099](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70099))

What followes is the long explanation.

Inside your exemple code there are some place that must be marked, to allow the discussion:

```
namespace impl {
  template <typename U = int>
  void f() {                       // (1) point of definition of the template f
    A<U> a{3};
    A<U> b{2};
    a += b;                        //  call operator += with arguments of dependent type A<U> 
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
  }
}

namespace impl {
  using namespace tools;          // using directive     
}

int main()
{
  impl::f();
}                                 // (2) point of instantiation of impl::f<int>
```

At the definition of the template `f` (1), the call to the operator += is performed with arguments of type `A<U>`. `A<U>` is a [dependent type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.dep#2), so `operator +=` is a [dependent name](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.dep.type#9.8).

[[temp.dep.res]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.dep.res#temp.dep.candidate-1) describe how `operator +=` is looked up:

> For a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules from the template definition context ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]). [ Note: For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), function declarations found in the template instantiation context are found by this lookup, as described in [basic.lookup.argdep]. — end note ][...]

There are two look-ups that are performed.

### Non argument dependent unqualified name look up [[basic.lookup.unqual]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lookup.unqual).

This look-up is performed *from the template definition context*. "*from the template definition context*" means *the context* at the point of definition of the template. The term "*context*" refers to the look-up context. If the template `f` was first declared in namespace `impl` and then defined in the global namespace scope, unqualified name look-up would still find members of namespace `impl`. This is why the rule [temp.dep.res]/1 use "*the template definition context*" and not simply "*template definition point*".

This look-up is performed from (1) and it does not find the `operator +=` defined in namespace `tools`. The using directive is appears later than (1), and has no effect.

### Argument dependent name look-up (ADL) [[basic.lookup.argdep]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lookup.argdep)

ADL is performed at the point of instantiation (2). So it is realized after the using directive. Nevertheless, ADL only considers namespace associated to the type of the arguments. The arguments have type `A<int>`, the template `A` is a member of the global namespace, so only members of this namespace can be find by ADL.

At (2) there are no `operator +=` declared in the global namespace scope. So ADL also fails to find a declaration for `operator +=`.

Answer (score 7):

Seems clang is right here according to [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.namespace#namespace.udir-2). In short - you are extending your namespace but `using namespace` should 'propagate' to this extension only forward.

> A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after the using-directive.
> During unqualified name lookup ([basic.lookup.unqual]), the names appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and the nominated namespace.
> [ Note: In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”.
> — end note
> ]

Comment: But this applies also to template functions? Because, if you remove all templates parameters in the code (say put ```U=int``` everywhere) then the code does not compile on gcc either. But with templates?

Comment: @francesco I suppose templates are the root cause of difference here since compileres have to treat them in semi-magical way (even though in most cases standard requires them to be treated as regular functions). I don't think they should be treated any differently then funcitons in this case

Answer (score 1):

#### Clang is right: unqualified dependent name lookup considers only declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template

In your example, the `operator+=` is a dependent name in the function template `f`, in which case unqualified name lookup for the `a += b;` call considers only declarations that are visible **at the point of definition** of the function template `f`. As the `tools` namespace is added as a nominated namespace to `impl` only **after** the point of definition of `f`, unqual. name lookup will not see the declarations brought in from `tools`, and will fail to `tools::operator+=`. Thus, Clang is right here, whereas GCC [as well as MSVC](https://msvc.godbolt.org/z/gBLbFC), is wrong in not rejecting the code.

This behaviour for GCC seems to only be present when the dependent name refers to an operator function, whereas if we replace the operator with a named function, GCC also rejects the code.

**Rejected by Clang, accepted by GCC:**

```
struct Dummy{};

namespace ns_g {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator!(T) { return true; } 
}  // namespace ns_f

namespace ns_f {
    template <typename T>
    void f() { 
        (void)(!T{});
    }
    
    // Add ns_g as a nominated namespace to ns_f
    // _after_ point of definition of ns_f::f.
    using namespace ns_g;
}  // namespace ns_f

int main() {
    ns_f::f<Dummy>();
    return 0;
}
```

**Rejected by both Clang and by GCC:**

```
struct Dummy{};

namespace ns_g {
    template <typename T>
    bool g(T) { return true; } 
}  // namespace ns_f

namespace ns_f {
    template <typename T>
    void f() { 
        (void)(g(T{}));
    }
    
    // Add ns_g as a nominated namespace to ns_f
    // _after_ point of definition of ns_f::f.
    using namespace ns_g;
}  // namespace ns_f

int main() {
    ns_f::f<Dummy>();
    return 0;
}
```

where, for the latter, GCC even gives us a note that:

> **note:** '`template<class T> bool ns_g::g(T)`' declared
> here, **later in the translation unit**.

This inconsistency alone hints that GCC is wrong in the former example, and we may not that [Clang's language compatibility page](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#dep_lookup) explicitly mentions that some versions of GCC may accept invalid code:

> #### Language Compatibility
>
> [...]
>
> **Unqualified lookup in templates**
>
> Some versions of GCC accept the following **invalid** code: [...]

Even if the particular example pointed out by Clang is rejected also by more recent GCC versions, the context of this questions is the same.

---

***Open bug report on GCC***

Note that the OP (and answerer) to a similar SO question (which I found long after all the answers landed on this question), to which this question is probably a duplicate:

- [Dependent name lookup in function template: clang rejects, gcc accepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818887/dependent-name-lookup-in-function-template-clang-rejects-gcc-accepts)

submitted a bug report on GCC that is yet to be claimed/addressed:

- [Bug 70099 - Function found by ADL, but shouldn't be visible at point of definition](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70099)

---

<sub>*(All ISO Standard references below refer to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/))*</sub>

#### Standard references

Even if [[temp.res]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#9) states [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> **[temp.res]/9** When looking for the declaration of a name used in a template
> definition, the usual lookup rules ([basic.lookup.unqual],
> [basic.lookup.argdep]) are used for non-dependent names. The lookup
> of names dependent on the template parameters **is postponed until the
> actual template argument is known** ([temp.dep]). [ Example: ... ]
> [...]

[[temp.dep.res]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.res#1) is clear that only declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template are considered for non-qualified (dependent) name lookup [**emphasis** mine]:

> **[temp.dep.res]/1** In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are
> considered:
>
> - (1.1) Declarations **that are visible at the point of definition of the template.**
> - (1.2) Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context ([temp.point])
>   and from the definition context.

a fact that is repeated in [[temp.dep.candidate]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.candidate#1) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **[temp.dep.candidate]/1** For a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name,
> the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules
> ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]) except that:
>
> - (1.1) For the part of the lookup **using unqualified name lookup**, **only function declarations from the template definition context are found**.
> - (1.2) For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), only function declarations found in either
>   the template definition context or the template instantiation context
>   are found.

where the wording *template definition context* is used instead of *point of definition of the template*, but afaik these are equivalent.

As per [[namespace.udir]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udir#2) [**emphasis** mine]:

> A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after the using-directive. During unqualified name lookup, the names appear **as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace** which contains both the using-directive and the nominated namespace. [ Note: In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”.  — end note ]

placing the using directive *after* the point of definition of the function template `f` is equivalent to simply declaring a name *after* the same point of definition, and as expected, the following modified example is rejected by Clang but accepted by GCC:

```
struct Dummy{};

namespace ns_f {
    template <typename T>
    void f() { 
        (void)(!T{});
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool operator!(T) { return true; } 
}  // namespace ns_f

int main() {
    ns_f::f<Dummy>();
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, note that ADL, (1.2) in [[temp.dep.candidate]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.candidate#1) above, does not apply here, as ADL do not proceed to enclosing scopes.

---

#### Non-dependent constructs may be diagnosed without instantiations

> **Additional note** An important point here is that `f` is a template function. Without template parameters the code would not compile neither with gcc, nor with clang.

If `A` were to be made into a non-template class, say

```
struct A { int x; };
```

then [[temp.res]/8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#8.3) applies, and the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required:

> **[temp.res]/8** Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> [...]
>
> (8.3) a hypothetical instantiation of a template **immediately following its definition** would be ill-formed **due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter**, or
>
> [...]

Comment: appears I was wrong. C++ is way to complicated sometimes

Comment: @bartop Tbh I just realized I don't actually know if Clang is correct or not. As per [temp.res]/9 dependent name lookup (including unqualified lookup for the dependent `operator+=` call) should be deferred until the template argument is known. At the call site of `impl::f();` in `main()`, the `impl` namespace has been extended with the `tools` namespace, and unqualified lookup should thus find the dependent operator overload.

Comment: @Oliv Any thoughts on the possible significant difference between _the point of definition of the template_ and _the template definition context_? From what I can tell, unqualified lookup in this context should be deferred until the template argument is known, thus the call site in `main()`, at which point `impl` has been extended with `tools`, at which point _from the definition context_ of `f`, the dependent `operator+=` name should find the overload in `tools`. I'm wondering whether [\[temp.point\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point) is relevant here.

Comment: @dfri No there is no significant difference. The new C++20 standard is clearer, maybe you should look inside it. Unqualified name lookup is performed from the template definition context. For the ADL part the context from which the lookup is performed is not realy significant: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.candidate#1.sentence-3

Comment: @Oliv thanks. From my reading the _the template definition context_ should just be spatial ("lookup-spatial"), and thus the dependent name lookup postponing rule of [temp.res]/9 applies to this spatial context, in which case the program in the OPs example should be well-formed.

Comment: @drfi The postponning is only there for ADL to be performed. But if ADL performed here is different that what it would have been considering all functions in associated namespace, the behavior is undefined. The reason of this rule is to allow template instantiation at link time.

Comment: @Oliv Yes and indeed ADL does not apply here. However [\[temp.res\]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#9) explicitly states that postponing applies also for unqualified name lookup, whereas [temp.dep.res]/1 is clear that unqualified lookup only finds declarations that are visible at _**the point of definition**_. I'm still unclear if this means _the **context** of the definition_ (as it is described in [temp.dep.candidate]/1) or if it actually means _**when**_ the function is defined (i.e., _prior_ to bringing in the nominated namespace `tools` to `impl`).

Comment: @dfri You could read the section "template definition" in the cpp reference page for unqualified name look up: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup